# How to prove substring is a partial order

Tags: partial-order

u is defined to be a substring of a string v if v = xuy for some string x and y. Either or both possibly empty.

How to you prove that a substring relation on any set of strings is a partial order?

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? Try using the definition of a partial order.

Comment: Do you know the proof for the subsets of a set $A$ ordered by $\subseteq$? If you do, what is different when you consider substrings?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: show that if $u$ is a substring of $v$ and $v$ is a substring of $w$ then $u$ is a substring of $w$.